# error: need ‘typename’ before ‘A<T*>::obj’ because ‘A<T*>’ is a dependent scope

Tags: c++, gcc

Suppose I have a class named A

```
template<class T>
class A
{
protected:
    static T* obj;

    A() {}
    ~A() {}

public:
    // methods...
};


// Somewhere in my source file...
template <class T> A <T*> ::obj = NULL;
```

For various reasons I need to declare a static member obj and gcc doesn't like them being initialized during the definition of the class (apparently you can do that with visual studio)

Anyway, how do I correctly declare obj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't partially specialize objects like that. Instead, just do this:

```
template <class T> T * A<T>::obj = NULL;
```

Make sure this goes in the *header* file along with the class template definition!

Comment: +1 but just a nit: i've started to very intentionally not follow the established convention of uppercase single letter template parameter names. i find them ungood on two counts: (1) macro name collision, and (2) that they reduce the typing for the person coding up the template, at the cost of increasing typing for the persons using the template (in general, but not above). so rather have the template parameter named e.g. `Type`, and then if it is to be provided to clients (say) then `t` is a nice short name, saving typing for them -- and shorter usage expressions. :-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Well, if your template starts with `typedef T type;`, then the problem is not as serious :-)

Comment: No sensible person would create a macro named "T". And T is used so commonly.